# Can I add/subtract value that is bound to an element property?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Does XAML allows modification of bound value?
Like `Width="{Binding Elementname="lstMine", Path=Width}" -100` ? So that I can have a relative value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use converters for this purpose, and my [WPF Converters](http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com) library includes an `ExpressionConverter` that allows you to do exactly that:

```
Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=lstMine, Converter={con:ExpressionConverter {}{0}-100}}"
```

Comment: can you please explain this part: {}{0}-100}

I came to know about this method after reading your answer and browsed Google to find: http://www.thejoyofcode.com/WPF_Quick_Tip_Converters_as_MarkupExtensions.aspx

is it the same?

Comment: @Sarath: the link you provided is to a converter with a very specific purpose: multiplication. The expression converter I provided takes pretty much any C# expression and evaluates it. For example, you could bind to ActualWidth and ActualHeight in a multi-binding, and calculate their sum with `{0}+{1}`. The numbers in the curly braces are placeholders for the bound values. The leading `{}` is just an escape mechanism in XAML to tell it not to treat the subsequent '{' as a markup extension. So the actual expression is simply `{0}-100`, and the `{0}` is substituted with the `Width`.

Comment: One last thing: you probably want `ActualWidth` rather than `Width`. The latter is not always set, and tells the layout engine how much width you'd like to allocate to the element, whereas the former is always set and contains the actual width allocated to the element, which is often different.

Comment: When my converter looks like `{}{0}-100`, I get an error: "Unexpected input '}-'. Expected '}'" I have to put a space before the subtraction sign `{}{0} - 100` for it to work

Comment: Soutions like this should become part of the WPF standard!

Answer (score 2):

use **Converter** for these purpose

Comment: Care to provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **converter**, its simple to use, doesn't require any libraries and is easy to customize if you want for example add value or multiply.

I got this one from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20220925173750/http://www.thejoyofcode.com/WPF_Quick_Tip_Converters_as_MarkupExtensions.aspx) post

**Converter class:**

```cs
public class SubtractConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object baseValue, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double val = System.Convert.ToDouble(baseValue);
        // Change here if you want other operations
        return val - Value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object baseValue, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Usage** (remember to add the namespace and the converter to window resources):

```xml
Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=lstMine, Converter={converters:SubtractConverter Value=15}}"
```