# Xaml. How to sum two bindings without the need of c# code

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to sum two bindings (numbers) in wpf .xaml without the need to use backend c# code. Is this doable and how?

I have two text blocks which I need to sum together to a 3rd one.

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="ChosenAmountValue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
Style="{DynamicResource BalanceDisplayDetailText}" Text="{Binding _Transfer.TransferAmount , StringFormat={}{0}.00}" IsEnabled="False" TextAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="SurchargeFeesValue" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Style="{DynamicResource BalanceDisplayDetailText}" Text="{Binding _Transfer.Fee.Value}" TextAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="SUM" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"  Style="{DynamicResource BalanceDisplayDetailText}"Text="{???}" TextAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"/>
```

Comment: What do you have access to? Because the easiest way is to have a separate property for this, the second easiest one is to have a converter (custom or [third party](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572432/can-i-add-subtract-value-that-is-bound-to-an-element-property)). XAML is not the best place for logic, it's not intended to make such operations (though there may be a way).

Answer (score 1):

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
     <converters:ValuesAdditionConverter x:Key="ValuesAddition" />
 </UserControl.Resources>

 <TextBlock x:Name="ChosenAmountValue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource BalanceDisplayDetailText}" Text="{Binding _Transfer.TransferAmount , StringFormat={}{0}.00}" IsEnabled="False" TextAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"/>
 <TextBlock x:Name="SurchargeFeesValue" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Style="{DynamicResource BalanceDisplayDetailText}" Text="{Binding _Transfer.Fee.Value}" TextAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"/>
 <TextBlock x:Name="SUM" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"  Style="{DynamicResource BalanceDisplayDetailText}" 
    TextAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
          <TextBlock.Text>
              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValuesAddition}" >
                   <Binding Path="_Transfer.TransferAmount"/>
                    <Binding Path=" _Transfer.Fee.Value" />
              </MultiBinding>
          </TextBlock.Text>
 </TextBlock>

and use a converter like this.

class ValuesAdditionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
     public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         return (int)values[0] + (int)values[1];
     }

     public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

Comment: you do realize that having a converter is actually c# code so it defeats the purpose of the answer ?

Comment: I am sorry, unfortunately I cannot use c# code, I am trying to do this either from existing converters or any othe rworkaround