# How to bind a child's property to a modified value of a parent property, such as height or width?

Tags: c#, wpf

I know that you can easily bind a height of a child to that of a parent with:

```
windowSelector.SetBinding(HeightProperty, 
    new Binding(nameof(mainWindow.ActualHeight)) { Source = mainWindow });
```

However, I am struggling to figure out how to bind to a modified version of that value, that is `mainWindow.ActualHeight` - 30 or perhaps even the height of one - the height of another?

Comment: One option would be to add a Converter (or MultiConverter for the second case) to the binding performing the required calculation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add/subtract value that is bound to an element property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572432/can-i-add-subtract-value-that-is-bound-to-an-element-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in the comment leads to an overcomplicated implementation of a `Converter`, but ultimately a `Converter` is what I needed, here is much more simple implementation of that.

Add an implementation of `IValueConverter`:

```
public class ValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return System.Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString()) + 
                   System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return System.Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString()) + 
                   System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to use it as a `Resource` in your window `XAML`:

```
<Window x:Class=...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ValueConverter x:Key="valueConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Then bind that `Converter`:

```
Height="{ Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=mainWindow, Converter={ StaticResource valueConverter }, ConverterParameter=-100 }"
```